# Android call same alert dialog in the entire application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a menu on Action Bar to change the password. And below is the code for it. I want to place this code such that I can call the same code anywhere in my application by clicking that menu. Is there any way?
--- ChangingPassword.java---

```
public void showDialog(final Context ctx, final String user_id, final String storedPass)
{

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.change_password, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

    // set prompts.xml to be the layout file of the alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText old_password = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.old_password);
    final EditText new_password = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.new_password);
    final EditText c_new_password = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.c_new_password);

    final int error_count;
    /*old_password.setTypeface(font);
    new_password.setTypeface(font);
    c_new_password.setTypeface(font);
    */
    final String old_pwd = old_password.getText().toString();
    final String new_pwd = new_password.getText().toString();
    final String c_new_pwd = c_new_password.getText().toString();
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setTitle("Change Login Password")
            .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                           if(old_pwd.equalsIgnoreCase("") || (old_pwd.equalsIgnoreCase(storedPass)))
                            {
                                old_password.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Enter a valid password</font>"));
                                old_password.requestFocus();
                            }

                            else if( new_pwd.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            {
                                new_password.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Enter a valid password</font>"));
                                new_password.requestFocus();
                            }

                            else if( c_new_pwd.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            {
                                c_new_password.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Enter a valid password</font>"));
                                c_new_password.requestFocus();
                            }

                            else if(!new_pwd.equals(c_new_pwd))
                            {
                                c_new_password.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Password & Confirm Passwords do not match</font>"));
                                c_new_password.requestFocus();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                try {

                                    UserTask task = new UserTask();
                                    String result = task.execute(new String[] {"changePassword",user_id,new_pwd}).get();
                                    System.out.print(result);
                                }

                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ""+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create an alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertD.show();
            //return alertD;

}
```

---Calling Activity ---
    new ChangePassword().showDialog(TeacherMain.this, user_id, password);
    return true;

Comment: Create a generic class and pass context to it and use method to show the AlertDialog

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kunu
i am a newbie so can u please elaborate with any example or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyDialog{
    public void showDialog(Context ctx)
    {
        /* Create dialog here and do whatever you are doing right now in your method*/
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

and call from your activity classes as below

```
new MyDialog().showDialog(ActivityName.this);
```

For your checking part you have to remove nested if statements

```
if(old_pwd.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        //print: Enter old password                                 
}else if( new_pwd.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
       //print: Enter new password 
}else if( c_new_pwd.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
      //print: Enter c_new_pwd 
}else if(! new_pwd.equals(c_new_pwd)){
      //print password doesnot match     
}else

{
            try {

                UserTask task = new UserTask();
                String result = task.execute(new String[] {"changePass",user_id}).get();
                 System.out.print(result);
            }catch (Exception e){
                  Toast.makeText(TeacherMain.this, ""+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


}
```

instead of creating new AlertDialog use 
alertDialogBuilder.show();

Comment: THANK u vry mch...
It will help me a lot.

Comment: try this and if you still have any problem then feel free to ask.

Comment: please post where exactly you are facing problem.

Comment: and your else part is only for `if(! new_pwd.equals(c_new_pwd))` this block. 
So make sure what you exactly want.

Comment: actually the problem is that when I am clicking OK button then it is getting submitted without chcking any validations. Please help me out in it..

Comment: i have tried dis too but still my alert dialog get dismiss when clicked on OK button

Comment: Are you getting any error? Because in this case if your password field is empty it won't go to the next if condition. It will check step by step. Previously it was checking each if condition.

Comment: No actually not getting error the dialog is getting dismissed

Comment: I need your updated code. Please update your code as well call from the activity.

Comment: try to use `alertDialogBuilder.show();` 
however it should work, you have to put Log in each condition and have to check where is your actual problem.

Comment: same issue getting dismissed

Comment: do you have any example or tutorial which could help out in dis

Comment: You will find similar kinda example if you search a little. However I feel you are missing a minor thing somewhere. Use log statement in your application and check till which point it is working fine.

And while calling the dialog class use `ActivityName.this`